# Rails design pattern: Large number of child models to override specific functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, decorator, sti

I have a model that will be called about 50 times to create 50 files with a rake task.

About 90% of the code can be re-used, but I need to override a few of the methods. I was thinking about just inheriting from the original table, but this could lead to around 40-50 models and that didn't feel right:

```
class Dog 
  def bark
     "woof"
  end
end

class Wolf << Dog
  def bark
     "growl"
  end
end
```

There's probably around 3-4 methods I will need to override in each model.

The other idea I had was to use the MODULE + EXTEND + SUPER DECORATOR from this post: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/14825364877/evaluating-alternative-decorator-implementations-in
I.e.

```
class Dog
  def bark
   "woof"
  end
end

module Wolf
  def bark
   "growl"
  end
end

dog = Dog.new
dog.extend(Wolf)
dog.bark   #growl
```

And then have 50 modules and extend the proper one at creation time.

So which would be the best option, or is there a better pattern for this situation ?

Comment: If you need several different sets of method implementations, then representing that as several classes inheriting from a common base is not necessarily a bad way to go.

Without knowing more about your specific case, however, it's hard to recommend any specific pattern. What does the generic model need to know from the specific and vice verse? Are the specific methods to be publicly exposed by the model? Do any of the model's generic methods need to be publicly exposed, etc?

Comment: I'm going to go for my second option I think. But the generic model will generate a base file more or less, it has everything it needs to do that. The specific model just needs to override about 4 of the methods (private) of the base class so they return different values, it actually shouldn't need access to anything from the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you describe the dependencies, this actually sounds like a perfect situation for the strategy pattern rather than subclassing or mixing in.

By subclassing or mixing in, you would be indicating that the specific might call methods of the base, and that it might extend the base API. Furthermore, private methods should always be treated as a potential code smell. If the specific is a strategy object (e.g. a module with module methods) that the base has an instance of and invokes methods of, then that provides the clearest specification of the dependencies you actually have.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance, http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StrategyPattern

Comment: Hadn't seen that strategy pattern before. Either that or the mixin should work for my situation.

Comment: I can tell you from experience that using mixins or subclasses where they are not absolutely required can cost significant time in maintenance later. If someone else wants to remove or rename a method on the base, for instance, they can't safely do so without first identifying and auditing all the subclasses or mixins to ensure that none of them depend on that method. That means that either time is wasted, or a worthwhile code change is skipped due to lack of sufficient time. Using a compositional pattern prevents this problem. Principle: "prefer composition over inheritance."